# Strip all data before a match

Tags: regex, perl

I have data in the following format.I need to strip all the data that appears before `<s:Envelope`.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 May 2017 09:52:02 GMT
Content-Length: 338962

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body><RetrieveStoredRoutesResponse xmlns="http://schema.website.com">
```

How can I do this using regular expression?

Comment: You're using Perl?  Just loop through the file and discard all the lines until you find one that starts with that pattern.

Comment: @dan1111 The data is present in a variable which is a respone from webservice.So I need a regex or something else to remove HTTP part

Comment: This is an HTTP response stream and in general the body may not necessarily start with `<s:Envelope`. To get the body one needs to strip off HTTP headers. This can be achieved with `s/\A(?:^HTTP.*?(?:^.+$)*^$)+//sm`. Demo: https://ideone.com/LEPpkQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an HTTP response stream of which you need only HTTP response body. In general the body may not necessarily start with `<s:Envelope`. To get the body you need to strip off HTTP headers. The headers are a series of non-empty lines followed by an empty line with first line starting with `HTTP`. A Perl regex substitution operator to remove the header is

```
s/\A(?:^HTTP.*?(?:^.+$)*^$)+//sm;
```

In this regex:

- `\A` matches the start of the entire input (note that `^` is used here to match start of a new line since `/m` is used)
- `(?:` - start of the outer non-capturing group. This group matches a single HTTP header block

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `HTTP` - `HTTP` literally
  - `.*?` - any text in non-greedy fashion (which effectively continues to the end of line due to the following `^`)
  - `(?:` - start of the inner non-capturing group. This group matches a single non-empty line

    - `^` - start of a line
    - `.+` - one or more chars (i.e. non-empty line)
    - `$` - end of the line
  - `)` - end of the inner non-capturing group.
  - `*` - repeat the the group (a non-empty line) zero or more times
- `)` - end of the outer non-capturing group.
- `+` - repeat the group (an HTTP headers block) one or more times

Perl demo: https://ideone.com/LEPpkQ

Comment: Complicated.I need some time to get a hang of this.It's working though.